# I got an indoor door to the garage installed and there is a 1/2 inch gap between the threshold and the door left for a weather seal. Is this right?

Tags: doors

I would like to know if this gap for weather seal should be left on a new door installation I would think that because is a new door should be cut to be close to the threshold. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You should install a weather seal. There may not be "weather" but there certainly is the potential of toxic gasses from any garage.

Comment: That makes sense. So the 1/2 inch is average for a weather seal ?

Comment: Is there an existing sweep on the bottom of the door? Many commercial sweeps span 1/2” quite easily.

Comment: For example, https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-1-1-4-in-x-36-in-L-Shape-Satin-Nickel-Door-Bottom-U36SN/204737254

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate No there is not. It is a brand new door and I the problem is I think it should have not been cut with that big gap but closer to the threshold as possible

Comment: The linked example, or something like it, will seal nicely. (If it was designed as an interior door with no weatherstripping at all, 1/2” is typical, for what it’s worth.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garage door is also a fire barriers.

Car exhaust barrier.

So you should install good seal.

1/2 inch is on high end, but you should be able to find a seal for it.